# ListViewCommand Set Extension with multiple options

Tags: spfx-extensions

I am trying to group multiple list commands using SPFx ListView Command Set extension. Is this possible?
See example:
[Example multiple list commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suLMC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible currently, this has been raised as a GitHub issue previously:

[How to group the list command using SPFx ListView Command Set extension?](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4645)

Though another answer on the SharePoint StackExchange suggests there may be a workaround using PnP PowerShell:

[How to add sub commands in my SPFX List View Command Set command](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/271708/91738)

Comment: Hi Callum,
Thank you for your response!
I also looked at the SharePoint/sp-dev-docs post. Too bad the uservoice system is no longer available. There is no similar post on the SharePoint feedback portal.
I do like the PnP workaround. The drawback is that it complicates the deployment process of the SPFx app. Some organisations may be hesitant to use it.

Comment: I would recommend adding your request to the Microsoft Feedback Portal, hopefully it will gain a lot of support from the development community.

Comment: Good plan. Will post on the feedback portal. tx.